# find2perl output does not compile

Tags: bash, perl, unix

This is my find command:

```
find /test-data -type f -mtime +2m
```

I then run find2perl /test-data -type f -mtime +2m. It generates:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted;



# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '/test-data');
exit;


sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&
    (int(-M _) > 2m)
    && print("$name\n");
}
```

This code generates errors. I am missing what is wrong.

syntax error at ./test_older_files.pl line 32, near "&& print("$name\n")"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line )) string starting on line 31)

Comment: The `2m` in `(int(-M _) > 2m)` is problematic. You'll have to pass a number of days or manually adjust that line. `-mtime 2m` isn't even valid for GNU `find`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, -M is only days, what if one wants minutes?

Comment: You can divide the difference between `time()` and the file's `mtime` (which is conveniently returned by `lstat`) by 60.

Comment: minutes would be `-mmin` in GNU find, but find2perl doesn't know that one.

Comment: (int(-M _) > 2m) vs (-M _) > 2/24 works

Answer (score 2):

`-mtime 2m` is not supported by `find2perl` (nor by GNU's `find`).

Put the following before the call to `find`:

```
 my $time = time();
```

Replace the `wanted` sub with the following:

```
sub wanted {
    my ($mtime);

    ( ($mtime) = ( lstat($_) )[9] ) &&
    -f _ &&
    ( $time-$mtime >= 2*60 )
    && print("$name\n");
}
```